# highlighting next <dd> tag after clicking an anchor

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, anchor

I'm using some code I found to highlight an id after clicking an anchor link.

I'd like to modify this to instead highlight the next `<dd>` tag in a definition list:

```
<dl class="mainfaq">
      <dt id="q1">Q1</dt>
         <dd><p>A1</p></dd>
      <dt id="q2">Q2</dt>
         <dd><p>A2</p></dd>
      <dt id="q3">Q3</dt>
         <dd><p>A3</p></dd>
</dl>
```

Here is the jquery from [Lincoln Loop](http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2009/apr/17/highlighting-named-anchors-jquery/)

```
    function highlight(elemId){
    var elem = $(elemId);
    elem.css("backgroundColor", "#ffffff"); // hack for Safari
    elem.animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffaa' }, 1500);
    setTimeout(function(){$(elemId).animate({ backgroundColor: "#ffffff" }, 3000)},1000);
}

if (document.location.hash) {
    highlight(document.location.hash);
}
$('a[href*=#]').click(function(){
    var elemId = '#' + $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
    highlight(elemId);
});
```

I can't seem to get the usual .next or .sibling modifications to work.

Comment: When you say "the next <dd> tag", the "next" in relation to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the n[ext adjacent sibling selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/):

```
highlight(elemId + ' + dd');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but assuming that you're clicking a link on the same page, and then trying to highlight the targeted element you could use a pure css solution:

```
:target + dd > p { /* css */ }
```

It should target the `p` that is a direct descendant of the `dd` which is the immediate sibling of a `target`-ed `dt` element.

There are some caveats to this approach, though; I cant' imagine that IE < 8 (and possibly including 8) will implement it properly. And it would almost certainly require a valid doctype.

Demo at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/): **http://jsbin.com/oqamu4**